# Swift: Adding UISegmentedControl/UITextField to dynamic UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a registration form application. The app allows users to create registration forms, and these registration forms are displayed using a UITableView. The questions can either be in the form of a text input (UITextField) or multiple choice (UISegmentedControl). I have the question creation working, but I cannot figure out how to display UITextFields and UISegmentedControls in the UITableView. This is the class I use to create a question:

```
class Question {
var Label: String
var required: Int

// create question
init (Label: String, required: Int) {
    self.Label = Label
    self.required = required

    if (self.required == 0) {
        self.Label = self.Label + " *"
    }
}

}

class textInput: Question {
var placeHolder: String

init (placeHolder: String, Label: String, required: Int) {
    self.placeHolder = placeHolder
    super.init(Label: Label, required: required)
}
}

class multiChoice: Question {
var answers: [String]

init(answers: [String], Label: String, required: Int) {
    self.answers = answers
    super.init(Label: Label, required: required)
}
}
```

Here is my current implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath. Obviously this will have to change to display the necessary contents.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.questionsArray[indexPath.row].Label
    return cell
}
```

One possible solution I was thinking of is making UITextField and UISegmentedControl class variables, so that they could be easily created and initialized in the class. However, I still do not know how to actually display them. I doubt there is a cell.textfield option. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try:

1. Create 1 custom UITableViewCell with the UITextField and other with the UISegmentedControl (don't forget to create an identifier for each kind of cell)
2. On your cellForRowAtIndexPathindexPath, check if the current question type is textInput or multiChoice and use the appropriate identifier to show the right cell.

I hope it helps

Comment: I'll give it a try! Makes a lot of sense! Appreciate the help:D

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to tell if it worked and accept the answer if it did :)

Comment: Cool! I'm glad for hearing that!